# Unity Inspector not reporting same rotation as script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I haven't used Unity in a while, and now I'm having trouble with the rotation vector. When I set the rotation to `(89, 0, 0)` in the inspector, transform.rotation.eulerAngles is `(89, 0, 0)` as well. But when I set it to `(91, 0, 0)`, my script returns `(89, 180, 180)`, and when I set it to `(-1, 0, 0)`, my script returns `(359, 0, 0)`.

My script is just:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class RotationMonitor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 vector;

    void Update()
    {
        vector = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    }
}
```

I'm really surprised I haven't noticed this yet, but is there a way to simply get the rotation displayed in the inspector in a script? (Obviously `(-10, 0, 0)` looks the same as `(350, 0, 0)`, but `(89, 180, 180)` isn't the same as `(91, 0, 0)`, if I want to be able to use the x value independently)

Edit:
Sorry, maybe I was a bit unclear in what I want. There aren't any parent objects, so I don't think it's an issue with local and global space. And as far as I understand, `(89, 180, 180)` is pretty much the same rotation as `(91, 0, 0)`. But if I want to get the x rotation independently of the other (lets say to rotate another object along the x axis), is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: This sounds like it may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please be more descriptive of why you are trying to get the inspector values. Is this for an editor script? If so, this is very easy. Is this for something at runtime? That would make an alternative method more effective (since no inspector exists at runtime).

Comment: I'm not explicitly trying to get the inspector values, and the script for runtime. I just added the `ExecuteInEditMode` attribute so that I wouldn't have to press play every time while trying this out. I'm just really confused by the way this seems to work. Even when I just say `transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.right * 125` and then `Debug.Log(transform.eulerAngles)` right after that, it outputs `(55, 180, 180)`. However, if I then look at the Inspector, it says that the object's rotation is `(125, 0, 0), just as I set it.` Does the Inspector get it's values from somewhere else?

Comment: And I'm really just trying to get the camera rotation along the x and y axis for a material.

Comment: That's right. The inspector has its own value that doesn't self-normalize the same way that transform.eulerAngles is always normalized. You can read it with [`TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation.html).

Comment: I'm kind of guessing at your goal here since the objective still hasn't been stated in very clear terms. Is this what you are asking for: A way to take an input euler angle representation, and produce an equivalent euler angle representation which has 0 for the y and z components if possible, or otherwise an equivalent euler angle representation which has 0 for the z component if possible.

Comment: Or maybe you just want the angle between Vector3.forward and the projection of transform.forward onto the y-z plane? That's one interpretation of "the x rotation independently of the other".

Comment: From Unity Doc [Transform.EulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) **When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.
**

Comment: **To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see the Quaternion * operator.**

Comment: @Ruzihm I solved my problem now. I really just forgot to multiply by PI somewhere else (I instead multiplied by 3 and therefore got weird behaviour) and then got completely confused when I tried debugging and the rotation values didn't behave as I expected. But thanks for explaining that Transform.eulerAngles is not the same as the rotation displayed in the inspector. I guess you were right about the XY problem, thanks for taking the time to explain that.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa Thanks to you as well, that just makes it even clearer. And thanks for the tip with the Quaternion's. I tried it out and they work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Transform.EulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html). Documentation clearly says inspector values are local rotations and more in link. Local rotation means, object rotation angles in the inspector showing according to parent element. As example if you have a parent objet and child object for that parent; if you change parent angle, in inspector both for parent and childs angle will change. But in script if you get **Transform.eulerAngles** you won't see any change. If you want Editor rotation value(Local rotation) use this [Transform.localRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html)

Comment: I'm just testing this on the main camera without any parent objects, therefore Transform.localRotation is the same as Transform.rotation for me